# Generate access_token and refresh_token after user registration in Spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

We are developing an application using Spring boot microservices.
We have one Authentication service with oauth2 system using spring security. there we are successfully getting access_token, refresh token through `oauth/token` request. We have implemented user signup also in the same service.
So my question is how can generate and return access_token and refresh_token for the new registered user in the same signup request.

Anyone can help us to get the answer?

Given below is my signup method. User is successfully inserted in the database.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public String createNewUser(@Valid @RequestBody SignUpRequest signUpDto, HttpServletRequest request,
        @RequestParam(value = "roletype") String roletype, BindingResult result, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws UserAlreadyExistAuthenticationException {
    userService.registerNewUser(signUpDto, roletype);

    try {

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    return "success";
}
```

Comment: why you want to return tokens in signup request? You should retrieve it during login/authentication process.

Comment: So do we need to send 2 request for a user registration?
For example, if a user is registering from a mobile application. The signup request is only for the data insert and after successfully inserted next request is for login ? Is that you mean ?

Comment: I have this same problem, whether I should send two requests or return refresh token during registration process